# Adding İtems in Shopping cart

Tags: asp.net-core

I've been working on my shopping cart program, but I keep having problems with adding an item to the shopping cart

here is my code;

HomeController class

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddToBasket(int id)
    {
        var basketJson = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SESSION_KEY);
        List<SepetProduct> sepet;
        if (basketJson == null)
        {
            sepet = new List<SepetProduct>();
        }
        else
        {
            sepet = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<SepetProduct>>(basketJson);
        }

        if (sepet.Any(x=> x.id == id))
        {
            sepet.Single(x => x.id == id).Toplam++;
        }
        else
        {
            sepet.Add(new SepetProduct { id = id, Toplam = 1 });
        }
        basketJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(sepet);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString(SESSION_KEY, basketJson);
        return Json(new { status = true, Msg = "Ürün Sepete Eklendi", Data = sepet });
    }
```

'''

and here is my Button action code

```
<form action="@Url.Action("addToBasket","Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@urun.UrunId" />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">
                                <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>Sepete ekle
                            </button>
                        </form>
```

The problem is that, when ı press to "sepete ekle" button, item was added to cart, but it directs us to a new page called "https://localhost:44302/Home/addToBasket"
and show us those data

'''
status  true
msg "Ürün Sepete Eklendi"
data
0
id  2
toplam  1

'''

I would like to when ı press to 'sepete ekle ' button,  the page remains the same, but the product is added to the basket. it just shows us a message saying added.

How can ı do that. thank you for interesting and helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use ajax to replace form post.Here is a working demo:

TestBasket.cshtml(I use `value="1"` to test.And add id="Id" to hidden input.Also,I need to change the type of button,so that when click it,it will not submit form,it will go to submitData() function.):

```
<form action="@Url.Action("addToBasket","Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="1" />
    <button type="button" onclick="submitData()" class="btn btn-dark">
        <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>Sepete ekle
    </button>
</form>
<script>
    function submitData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("addToBasket","Home")',
            data: { "id": $("#Id").val() }
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data.msg);
            });
    }
    </script>
```

HomeController:

```
public IActionResult TestBasket()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddToBasket(int id)
        {
           
            return Json(new { status = true, Msg = "Ürün Sepete Eklendi", Data = new List<SepetProduct>() });
        }
```

result:
[image]